# Change Database Automaticly after certain time

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I wonder how to get my Database Table to change at a certain time.

**Example :**

After 1 hour after submitting the form automaticly change to Prio 2 
After 3 hours  automaticly change to Prio 3

Thats what I need..

This is the code I use to read the table :

```
<?php
                                    include("db.php");

                                    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lijst where archief='0' ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(prio, '#ffaeae,#fff5ae,#ffffff')");

                                    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                    {
                                        $id = $test['ticketID'];
                                        echo"<tr style='background:". $test['prio'].";'>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>".$test['aangemeld']."</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td>".$test['status']."</td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['klant']."</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['naam']."</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['achternaam']. "</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['telefoon']. "</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['onderwerp']. "</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td width='300px'><font color='black'>". $test['probleem']. "</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['terugb']. "</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['Tijd']. " door : ". $test['wijziging']. "</font></td>";
                                        echo"<td><a href ='view.php?ticketID=$id'><small class='icon pencil'></small><span>Wijzig</span></a><br /><a href ='move.php?ticketID=$id'>Afgehandeld</a></td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                    mysql_close($conn);
                                    ?>
```

Comment: `cron jobs` will help u. read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run a scheduled task or cron. You have to call your script as often as you want to update the data in the tables. The script should check if the time since the creation is bigger than one-two... hours. If yes, than it should change the prio. Assuming that you are using timestamps, the code should be something like this:

```php
if ( time() - (60 * 60) >= $myData['created'] )
  changePrio($myData['id'], 2);
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use this.

Comment: I dont know where I should place the code you gave me. And no idea how it should change the value's in my database.

First value ( standard = #ffffff ) | After 1 hour The value must be #fff5ae | After 2 hours the value has to be #ffaeae

Comment: This should go to a separate file, and you should call this file periodically, like every 1 minute. It depends on how often you want to update the table. The script I inserted above will do the check if the record is older than one hour (not checking if it is less than two hours). If yes, then it will call the function (you have to write it) which updates the records in your database.